# Javascript regExp cyrillic pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I know that this is a dumb question, but i spent two days googling without any result.
What the regExp pattern should be to allow my user to type only cyrillic characters and spaces?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason for limiting your users to certain characters?

Comment: @Matti: That’s a very good question. Normally, you do not wish to do that, but sometimes it is reasonable to limit input fields to only decimal digits `\p{Nd}`, or only numbers `\pN`, or only math figures `\p{Math}`, or only letters `\pL`, or only alphabetics `\p{Alphabetic}`, or **most especially** only characters that are all of either one or two scripts or of type Common. That avoids some security pitfalls such as B≢Β≢В (i.e., U+0042 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B vs U+0392 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA vs U+0412 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER VE). Some are intractable, though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in Javascript because Javascript does not provide even the most basic [Level 1 Unicode support](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support) in its regexes. You would have to switch languages to do this correctly.

You cannot use enumerated block ranges for this.  That confuses blocks and scripts, which is deeply flawed. There are 150 code points that have the `\p{Script=Cyrillic}` property but which lack the `\p{Block=Cyrillic}` property. They are in different blocks.  Watch:

```
$ unichars '\p{Script=Cyrillic}' '\P{Block=Cyrillic}' | wc -l
150
```

Furthermore, there are a couple of non-Cyrillic code points within the Cyrillic block.

The best you could do is to enumerate all 404 Cyrillic code points as a character class, which may prove prohibitively large.

```
$ unichars '\p{Script=Cyrillic}'  | wc -l
404
```

You can use [the *unichars* scripts](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) to list those all out if you really want to. You might also want to grab [the *uniprops* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops) while you’re there.

Comment: OK then. How can i test it with php. I will try with ajax.

Comment: @Emil: I believe that if you use PHP’s preg (“perl regex”) functions, you **should** be able to use a character class like `[\s\p{IsCyrillic}]`, because `\p{IsCyrillic}` should be an alias for `\p{Script=Cyrillic}`. There are a couple of other possible languages, too, but basically you have to have support for Unicode script properties to get this to work properly. BTW, you might also want to allow any character of script-type Common via `\p{IsCommon}`. Those are the regular punctuation marks and such, including spaces. The *uniprops* script I mentioned can list all a code point’s properties.

Comment: @Emil: Upon reading the *pcrepattern* man page to see how `preg` patterns should work in PHP, it looks like **if** the PCRE library that PHP is linked against has been built/compiled with Unicode support (which is site-dependent), then PCRE and thence PHP use the short-cut aliases for script properties, so its `\p{Cyrillic}` is how you express `\p{Script=Cyrillic}`. You could also use Perl 5.6 or later, Ruby 1.9 or later, or Java 1.7 or later for access to script properties. **CAREFUL:** You cannot use C♯ ’cause its `\p{Cyrillic}` is evilly `\p{Block=Cyrillic}` not `\p{Script=Cyrillic}`.

Comment: DONE! 
`
$pattrn = "/[\sабвгдАБВГД]/"
preg_match($myvar, $pattern);
`

Comment: @Emil: I had no idea you had **specific** Cyrillic characters in mind!

Comment: i had not. This is only for the example

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny hack that you can put to make this work (not very confident of it's accuracy though, hence, kindly check carefully before using in production):

```
`/^[\u0400-\u04FF\s]+$/`
(/^[\u0400-\u04FF\s]+$/).test("Привет мир") //true
```

Although I am not very sure about the unicode support but as per wikipedia, the characters in the the Cyrillic range lie generally within (U+0400-U+04FF) and this regexp also includes white spaces and this snippet worked in my browser console.